# Smartparens strict mode C-w kill line if no active region

Tags: smartparens

I'm using smartparens-strict-mode and trying to get it so that C-w kills a region if selected and the whole line that point is on if not (like [this](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/copying-lines-without-selecting-them.html) but working with smartparens strict mode).

This is what I have so far:

```
(defun sp-kill-line-or-region (orig-fun &rest args)
    "Kill whole line if region not selected."
    (if (region-active-p)
        (apply orig-fun args)
      (kill-whole-line)))
  (advice-add 'sp-kill-region :around 'sp-kill-line-or-region)
```

But it doesn't work. If I just do C-w it gives me the error `command-execute: The mark is not set now, so there is no region`. However, if I mark something, then C-w, then I can use it like I want (i.e. I can then not mark anything and it will kill the whole line).

I can't figure this one out for whatever reason. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Advices suck.  Much easier is to just define a new function and bind it to `C-w`.  This is what I use:

```
(defun my-kill-region-or-word (&optional arg)
  "Kill active region or one word backward."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (sp-kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (if smartparens-strict-mode
        (sp-backward-kill-word arg)
      (backward-kill-word arg))))
```

Replace the else branch with `sp-kill-whole-line`, so this code should work

```
(defun my-kill-region-or-line (&optional arg)
  "Kill active region or current line."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (sp-kill-region (region-beginning) (region-end)) ;; strict-mode version of kill-region
    (sp-kill-whole-line))) ;; strict-mode version of kill-whole-line
```

You can of course make it strict-mode aware by wrapping the commands with if as I do in my function.